# Camera with "track to" empty goes insanely fast

Tags: camera, tracking, empty

[image]

It's hard to see with the GIF but the camera stutter.
I've tried to apply the scale on both empty and camera, nothing changed...
However if you have more ideas on how to track the camera in a smooth and precise way I would appreciate that!

Comment: The image is too small. Check the parenting relationships of your camera and target. Please share a larger screenshot of your expanded Outliner and the Constraints properties tab.